# Deal with nested for-comprehension and futures in scala (value map is not a member of Any)

Tags: scala, future, flatmap, for-comprehension

I saw many questions related to mine but none deal with my case.

I want to nest for-comprehension of future like in the code below:

```
def getVal(v: Int): Future[Double] = {
  Future(scala.math.sqrt(v >> 3))
}

val c = true
val t = for {

  x <- getVal(60)
  y <- getVal(52)
  o <-
    if (c) {
      for {
        a <- getVal(10)
        b <- getVal(5)
      } yield a > b
    } else true

} yield x >= y && o
```

but my code can't compile I got this error : `value map is not a member of Any`

I need help, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
    if (c) {
      for {
        a <- getVal(10)
        b <- getVal(5)
      } yield a > b
    } else true
```

Because it does (pseudocode):

```
   if (c) Future[Boolean]
   else Boolean
```

The code common type is inferred to `Any` and then you end up with for-comprehension trying to call .map on `Any` value.

Just wrap `true` with `Future.successful(true)`.